# Centered images within left-aligned text

Tags: css, image, text, block

I'd like inline (appearing on the same line) but centered images within a block of left-aligned text.

Please see here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2LHfA/4/

```
.extra {
display:table;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}

.extra img {
display: inline;
?????
}
```

Can I do this with only CSS (without messing with the HTML)?

I've tried "text-align: center;" and "margin: 0 auto;" to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: want to center the images ?

Comment: How can they be centered, if they are inline? I think you want inline-block or block; You could wrap them in a parent element, and make it block, then center the images within that parent block element. IF you have control over the HTML. From the looks of your use of `<br/>`, it seems like this is what you'd want to do anyways.

Answer (score 2):

**IF YOU CAN EDIT THE HTML:**
I'd wrap the images inside another div and center align the contents of it via text-align property.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
     <div class="fish">
        <img src=http://i.imgur.com/innn2oL.gif />
        <img src=http://i.imgur.com/zRYKaCM.jpg />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .fish{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
 }
```

**IF YOU CAN'T EDIT THE HTML:**
You have two options:

1. Considering injecting the parent div (.fish) via Javascript and use the
   method above.
2. Give the first image some left margin to push the images
   towards the center via nth-of-type* psuedo-class as below. This won't be an exact centering, but a work-around.

   ```
   .extra img:nth-of-type(1){
        margin-left:20%;
    }
   ```

*nth-of-type may not be supported by all browsers.

Comment: Judging by the fiddle by the OP, it seems that this is what he/she is trying to do anyways. It doesn't make sense to center images `inline`. How would that even work?

Comment: I guess I misused "inline"; I just want them to appear on the same line.  I don't have control over the HTML, which is why adding a parent div wouldn't work.  Any other suggestions, or is it simply impossible to do this via CSS only?  Thanks for the suggestions though :)

Comment: I see. I've updated my post. Please take a look and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have access to Javascript.  Adding a percentage isn't perfect (e.g. in the case of one image, vs two or five), but it does get it closer to the center.  I'll use that for now.

Comment: Cool. If you can specify the width of the .extra div and/or the images that are inserted, you can get pretty close to absolute center (as long as the image quantity is the same for each post).

Comment: I _can_ specify the width of div.extra; unfortunately, the image dimensions and quantities do vary.